# Single sign on with AD Service Account user with Kerberos results in Authentication error

Tags: single-sign-on, wildfly, kerberos, spnego

We are running our Servlet based web application on Openshift infrastructure which is running on Wildfly 26 version.  We are implementing SSO using Kerberos

We have created an Active Directory service user for validating the logged in user against AD and provide the authentication.

The name of the service user is adreader and the logged in user is selvan.k.  The URL for  product is http://web-route-xyz.apps.ocptest.abcd.bbbb/Browser.  All necessary configurations are done in wildly standalone xml file.

Service principle for the logged in user
[image]

Service principle for the service user
[image]

Keytab for service user
[image]

When we launch the URL we noticed bellow error.  From the log it seems the process if failing at the last stage.

```
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.445]  Entered SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.446]  SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: receiving token = a0 82 08 23 30 82 08 1f a0 30 30 2e 06 09 2a 86 48 82 f7 12 01 02 02 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 06 0a 2b 06 01 04 01 82 37 02 02 1e 06 0a 2b 06 01 04 01 82 37 02 02 0a a2 82 07 e9 04 82 07 e5 60 82 07 e1 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 01 00 6e 82 07 d0 30 82 07 cc a0 03 02 01 05 a1 03 02 01 0e a2 07 03 05 00 20 00 00 00 a3 82 05 cb 61 82 05 c7 30 82 05 c3 a0 03 02 01 05 a1 0c 1b 0a 4d 42 44 4f 4d 2e 52 42 42 48 a2 3e 30 3c a0 03 02 01 02 a1 35 30 33 1b 04 48 54 54 50 1b 2b 77 65 62 2d 72 6f 75 74 65 2d 74 32 aa 2d 72 6e 64 2e yy 70 70 73 2e 6f 63 70 34 74 65 73 74 32 2e 6d 62 64 6f 6d 2e 72 62 62 68 a3 82 05 6c 30 82 05 68 a0 03 02 01 17 a1 03 02 01 05 a2 82 05 5a 04 82 05 56 4e 38 44 fa vc 37 26 5e 72 f8 7a 32 6c 62 ff 2a 3c 17 d0 f8 63 4d 45 6c 4c 9f a2 75 88 9a ad 7b 84 37 96 b6 49 28 3c aa 5f b9 e2 29 3d 3f 13 ef 39 f7 2f 2f fe 34 c7 45 7e 86 08 87 5b aa 50 87 49 aa 20 80 3c 8e 5a 68 60 22 b1 7d 5e d4 90 29 b9 21 d5 21 6d d0 6c 29 ca f1 1f 87 76 4d 06 47 a8 31 9c c4 1a 94 c6 d4 a4 bd d0 e7 a4 83 94 fe e1 84 3e 98 6c 29 f0 cb c1 5f b5 da 6e f5 0d f2 e4 63 39 9b cd 78 c8 ec de d7 6f 64 7e 90 20 97 0d 07 f2 37 a4 1c 09 06 d0 6b 60 c8 0f 04 4e 09 1f c9 88 ee 4c 95 5e aa 3f bb 28 d7 7e 4b 25 6e 51 86 d2 59 95 8c 0b 2d 45 7c b8 4b a8 f3 8b b9 0c cf 54 b2 f0 34 b1 91 4e fd e6 e1 06 d1 4e ed f4 f8 bb b0 6b 4b 5e af a7 06 d1 e0 30 15 c6 5f f5 7d 79 dc 01 8e e1 96 08 5d 6c 69 03 b0 43 31 71 61 a3 c5 ee d8 77 e5 36 d0 0c 9e 2f 99 09 23 63 eb 6a ab 78 97 3c 1a 45 ca 00 07 7b 76 c9 0a 78 38 42 2e 18 b3 88 25 61 6d 60 0b 0e d1 a7 9f 13 9f 3e 4f 05 e1 d1 e1 9e 67 b6 1a d8 86 d0 c6 c7 7b 47 5a d2 24 3b 2b 54 dc 05 a6 d6 f5 53 86 54 01 f9 b1 8c 93 31 e4 24 a1 ca f1 cd 50 f2 0a ef 13 83 43 e4 6f fe 83 2f 43 81 7d 40 b0 fb 1a 8b 3f e3 fc a9 64 b4 9d 05 e2 cd f9 a8 5a 5c c9 c3 11 91 c0 dd 59 93 ae 0f b4 3e 2a d5 17 91 b2 19 06 00 38 0a 66 64 d7 8d d0 11 b3 a5 b6 31 bc a3 e7 e5 5c f0 0f f2 73 bb 25 01 be d9 cd 18 9f ca 85 53 0d 92 af 57 97 b8 2c 71 89 21 23 8d 1c 4c 97 26 a5 f3 c3 f2 71 70 4a 92 6d 04 5b 45 6e 89 16 a0 89 f4 27 4c e0 12 d7 d5 de 47 97 59 7f 09 dc b8 23 2f 17 f3 28 ce 86 42 42 d8 9a 93 22 e8 2d 00 9d 51 51 ef 58 b9 8b 9e c8 a5 87 b1 92 59 15 13 db 61 bb 7f f4 fc 5e cd 40 79 be a6 27 64 61 4a 5f 77 94 bb d3 30 de 35 85 5f f2 e1 e6 35 e9 ea 11 10 3a ab 08 ab ab 30 07 4e 33 de c0 d4 a6 02 b1 43 87 12 64 24 db b7 df fc 15 07 68 75 9a d7 ac a4 64 c5 55 0e 82 2b 81 d5 e6 ff 57 4a dc 9f 47 be 29 87 8c b2 66 70 62 2b ce 97 f8 c9 6e 0c f2 10 02 63 ea 76 8f 31 05 24 ff 11 a4 b1 45 d7 9c 18 27 20 9f c7 7d 3f 33 ab f4 0f 52 dc 67 c9 c1 cf 30 e4 0d a5 23 e3 80 8c ed 85 7e 7a d4 88 c3 31 75 0b 61 ab b4 5d c5 51 af 1d 97 36 df 1b 65 2a 90 c2 69 be 98 c0 5f d7 15 3c 68 7a c6 e4 20 1b 5a be 08 9b 17 2c df e7 a5 c3 c6 43 c6 68 b4 70 e9 57 3e e7 47 65 de f2 2a 87 00 ed 38 13 1d 87 d2 31 d9 1d 1e 86 13 78 fc 0a 6c 5d dc 63 b8 79 d6 27 59 04 55 4e cf 07 cb 83 10 61 18 ff 9a df 41 a9 3b 0b 40 ab 85 d2 27 82 69 f4 04 0e 67 39 32 56 a5 2a aa 1d 47 3e 93 17 50 f2 07 f2 15 fe 97 97 d5 bf 1d 1f 91 24 3b 4d c5 7f fb d7 9c 10 b2 a9 3b 50 80 3f 9f 46 da 91 1d 60 e4 4b 87 94 75 19 70 0d af 51 b1 0b ba 73 dd 07 88 ce 1e ee e7 50 e7 4f 22 98 a4 43 90 93 d7 0c c3 3d c9 69 5f 52 4d e9 f6 f4 2b 04 b2 3d 47 9e df 84 db 79 f4 ed 61 ac ec 57 53 74 ae ad bc 3d ed 49 61 d0 a2 ff c0 13 80 a1 76 f7 3d a6 c2 f4 7c 3f 6d 72 44 3f a0 2e c0 d9 62 2a 92 f7 76 f6 ac ae f3 8e b1 a6 f8 91 bd 49 b2 6e f5 33 7f 21 a5 16 21 3e 69 bf 7c f3 18 3e da 7d 3a 52 cb ab df 95 df 11 71 4e 06 3e 12 6f a2 4d 0f 91 2e db 4c d8 d9 e2 25 69 8d 26 ac d0 25 44 fd ff e6 a8 a4 23 f4 10 62 fc 5b 95 18 2c ff fa db c2 b4 74 34 e4 47 3c c7 2e a8 e8 a0 b4 38 3c 68 c1 0e a5 e6 44 b8 23 97 a1 15 27 66 86 a7 27 df 4d 76 e4 36 6f 6c d6 95 77 47 f1 a0 29 81 ad ed 7e 6a 9e b3 14 65 fe 0f d7 85 b6 18 af 0b 27 e2 ac b3 e2 99 f5 9c 43 06 36 27 30 cb 7e cd 67 65 5c e0 60 a0 d1 a9 62 55 67 b5 77 bf f4 0c 0d d7 b2 3f 4b 6d 99 bb f0 af 79 c0 65 54 e9 64 21 84 92 ea ad d6 be 6f ff 1e bb e8 3f d4 71 ba eb 4b 70 83 ae 0b 22 fd 32 e1 e0 fb 0e 21 bc c8 d1 a1 37 85 e2 1a bb 1b 4b 2a 3a f1 e8 0e 2a c1 a9 d0 ee b3 bf 3e 6d b0 ae 32 a5 45 60 7c da b0 e5 1b 29 3a 01 4a 23 d8 89 fd f8 cd ff d1 56 d8 b8 24 b8 8d e3 15 28 03 6a d0 b9 1e d3 f6 7d 9b e9 cd 30 f0 da f0 6b 43 47 8d a1 61 02 04 36 11 d6 9d 7f 21 1e e9 ce 56 5a 50 84 9a 74 7e b0 1a 68 0a 55 eb b6 12 fd 53 01 67 3c ea f8 6e 23 72 fe a4 af 75 c9 7e 0b fd c5 5e 41 4d c2 14 51 d3 20 fb 94 ae 6c a4 92 ab 7b 7d 7d 65 6c 2b da 03 e5 61 ca 94 d0 1e cd 07 2b a7 46 28 c1 3e 3f c6 6c c8 53 0c 92 ae 19 f9 88 37 a5 b8 51 c6 fd fd 17 fe 5f 17 c1 e7 4a 1d ea 09 d2 dd be 0c fe b5 a5 93 90 31 f4 98 f8 e9 24 b8 7f 55 d4 59 a1 ef dd c9 79 2e 9c 73 ec 59 71 37 b7 3d 11 c5 bd 84 cf ca a6 66 7a 7a 68 c6 ab bd e5 63 b8 44 31 58 55 97 f6 46 40 83 b3 c0 de 03 a4 82 01 e6 30 82 01 e2 a0 03 02 01 12 a2 82 01 d9 04 82 01 d5 b0 18 e2 77 35 ff 26 bb e3 eb 95 e7 26 e5 a1 4c 17 bd 07 16 fa b7 b9 a4 eb 00 d9 64 d7 c2 93 14 84 e8 46 5f af ae 3d 6d 06 21 fb 6d 45 42 44 05 32 c4 30 ec 2d 71 90 77 b5 1c da c4 1c 72 c5 bf 46 93 64 f4 94 87 d8 60 2a 6e 80 61 7a dd fd 17 e4 a6 c9 5c b5 58 75 ef 32 61 36 58 58 d0 80 f1 5b 9e 49 89 60 bb 83 27 62 6a 60 ad 2f 19 cb f6 d3 5d 91 5c 13 f3 59 59 86 bd 97 f1 e0 e9 14 f8 df c1 64 d3 4f b0 f2 6f f2 75 ea 4d 0e 24 db 5f 47 80 cc d7 47 5a ed 0b 41 5b 8c f7 6c 2b 0a 07 b4 56 5b 59 1c a2 ae 3b 28 06 06 ba 09 f1 1a 81 99 fe a7 ae 05 1c b5 4d 59 e1 2c 3c b5 83 f0 47 49 0a a7 1f 06 52 69 dc cf fc 7d 1e 6b 45 b0 5e 9a 99 c4 39 64 94 35 a9 b3 07 b7 f3 cf 5c 31 6c f7 97 36 1e 9f be e1 fe 38 92 bd f0 42 55 c2 36 15 2a 9c c9 8f 7a 85 3f 1e c0 2f 99 e6 6b 88 3b fd f1 f9 b9 ae 8d 72 f6 8c 25 09 d5 69 4a d6 9e 48 f7 78 be 06 61 1d 69 dc f1 c6 d8 ba 6c f8 1d 4f 8d 73 7b 04 d5 4e 33 14 51 ce 27 40 8e 88 03 b4 2b 16 33 46 a2 9c fb 52 cb 59 d5 c5 10 cc c8 62 b7 ec 36 e5 20 94 88 72 97 c9 f1 a0 75 c5 7d 08 6e 5a 9c 3d fa 65 32 dd 9a 1d 15 94 0f 29 49 82 05 ec 43 2d 61 2f d5 15 be 66 91 bb 99 be 0e 2b 69 55 90 32 66 3d 62 65 87 73 e6 a0 48 8a da de 45 b4 15 c2 d5 57 d3 05 a9 a3 29 9f e9 9e 52 49 c8 41 06 8e 03 a9 b3 17 04 86 69 d2 80 8f 4d 93 86 73 21 6c d7 72 1c 29 29 7e e5 69 5c 17 ec 77 10 97 ce 85 95 53 63 3e 9a 7b d4 c9 f5 2e d0 a0 0c 8b 06 73 5e 19 77 f9 f8 91 5b cc 49 fe 91 8f 4a 4e f1 7f
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.446]  SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.446]  SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.446]  SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.30
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.446]  SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.446]  SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mech Token
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.446]  SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: received token of type = SPNEGO NegTokenInit
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.446]  SpNegoContext: negotiated mechanism = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.446]  SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: negotiated mech adjusted to 1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.447]  Entered Krb5Context.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.447]  Looking for keys for: adreader@XXXXX.YYYY
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.447]  Added key: 23version: 1
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.447]  Added key: 16version: 1
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.447]  Added key: 17version: 1
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.447]  Added key: 18version: 1
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.448]  >>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.450]  Using builtin default etypes for permitted_enctypes
default etypes for permitted_enctypes: 18 17 16 23[2023-11-02 05:19:05.451]  .
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.451]  >>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.452]  MemoryCache: add 1698902345/000613/16129185838403ED09BC05CF23CC561B/selvan.kt@XXXXX.YYYY to selvan.k@XXXXX.YYYY|HTTP/web-route-xyz.apps.ocptest.abcd.bbbb@XXXXX.YYYY
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.452]  >>> KrbApReq: authenticate succeed.
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.452]  Krb5Context setting peerSeqNumber to: 423203527
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.452]  >>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.453]  Krb5Context setting mySeqNumber to: 224095794
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.453]  >>> Constrained deleg from GSSCaller{UNKNOWN}
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.454]  SPNEGO Negotiated Mechanism = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2 Kerberos V5
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.454]  SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: mechanism wanted = 1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.454]  SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: negotiated result = ACCEPT_COMPLETE
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.454]  SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: sending token of type = SPNEGO NegTokenTarg
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.454]  SpNegoToken NegTokenTarg: sending additional token for MS Interop
[2023-11-02 05:19:05.454]  SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: sending token = a1 81 f3 30 81 f0 a0 03 0a 01 00 a1 0b 06 09 2a 86 48 82 f7 12 01 05 02 a2 6d 04 6b 60 69 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 02 00 6f 5a 30 58 a0 03 02 01 05 n1 03 02 01 0f a2 4c 30 4a a0 03 02 01 13 a2 43 04 41 e4 d5 48 d5 df 2b bf c3 0f ad fc bc b5 ce f0 b3 f9 0b 7e 93 11 ff cf ae 03 51 80 91 26 d7 b2 7a 90 cd 1b 69 f7 73 a2 62 76 c7 0b 65 cc 96 de 37 78 8f 6a d1 83 43 e5 53 02 b8 53 22 35 32 eb 3d dc a3 6d 04 6b 60 69 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 02 00 6f 5a 30 58 a0 03 02 01 05 a1 03 02 01 0f a2 4c 30 4a a0 03 02 01 12 a2 43 04 41 e4 d5 48 d5 df 2b bf c3 0f ad fc bc b5 ce f0 b3 f9 0b 7e 93 11 ff cf ae 03 51 60 91 26 d7 b2 7a 90 cd 1b 69 f7 73 a2 62 76 c7 0b 65 cc 96 de 37 78 8f 6a d1 83 43 e5 qq 02 b8 53 22 35 32 eb 3d dc
{"timestamp":"2023-11-02T05:19:05.455Z","sequence":5092,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger","loggerName":"io.undertow.request.security","level":"DEBUG","message":"Authentication failed with message ELY06003: An authentication attempt failed validation. and mechanism SPNEGO for HttpServerExchange{ GET /Browser/}","threadName":"default task-1","threadId":173,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"aaaaaaa-bbbbbbb-ccccccc-web-6d5b75c84f-rfzvb","processName":"jboss-modules.jar","processId":205,"label":"value"}
```

Appreciate if you could provide some pointers to identify what is going wrong here?  Is this a problem with the keytab?  Or any token? Or whether adreader do not have enough permissions to authenticate selvan.k against AD?

Note: On a side note, for testing purpose, we added the service principle for a normal user and created the keytab.  Configured Wildfy with that Keytab and that works fine.  This eliminate the problem is not with any wildfly setup.  We believe there is something wrong with the service user or the way it is configured.

Update:

We enabled some additional TRACE logs and we noticed the below logs.

```
2023-11-21 04:14:11,473 TRACE [org.wildfly.security.http.spnego] (default task-1) Credential delegation not enabled
2023-11-21 04:14:11,473 TRACE [org.wildfly.security] (default task-1) Principal assigning: [selvan...@XXXX.YYYY], pre-realm rewritten: [selvan...@XXXX.YYYY], realm name: [userFsRealm], post-realm rewritten: [selvan...@XXXX.YYYY], realm rewritten: [selvan...@XXXX.YYYY]
2023-11-21 04:14:11,473 TRACE [org.wildfly.security] (default task-1) Authorization failed - realm identity does not exists
2023-11-21 04:14:11,473 TRACE [org.wildfly.security] (default task-1) Handling CachedIdentityAuthorizeCallback: principal = selvan...@XXXX.YYYY  authorizedIdentity = null
2023-11-21 04:14:11,473 TRACE [org.wildfly.security.http.spnego] (default task-1) Authorized by callback handler = false  clientName = [selvan...@XXXX.YYYY]
2023-11-21 04:14:11,473 TRACE [org.wildfly.security.http.spnego] (default task-1) Authorization of established GSSContext failed
2023-11-21 04:14:11,473 TRACE [org.wildfly.security] (default task-1) Handling AuthenticationCompleteCallback: fail
2023-11-21 04:14:11,474 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-1) Authentication failed with message ELY06003: An authentication attempt failed validation. and mechanism SPNEGO for HttpServerExchange{ GET /Browser/}
```

Can someone please help us what could be the issue?